# Show positive real axis and open unit disc are surjectively invariant under $p(z) = z^2, z \in \mathbb C$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, proof-verification

Definition: if $X \subseteq \mathbb C$ satisfies $f[X] = X$, we say $X$ is surjectively invariant under $f$.

Proofs:

about open unit disc:

Let $z = re^{i\theta}$ be a point on the open unit disk where $r < 1.$ Then $p(z) = (re^{i\theta})^2 = r^2e^{i(2\theta)} = se^{i\phi}$ where $r^2 = s  < 1$ and $2\theta = \phi$. So we see that the open unit disc is copied from the $xy$-plane to the $uv$-plane without any alteration.

Now that I wrote this down, I am not sure if this claim can stand up. Particularly, I am not sure what to do with $2\theta$ once we get the point $w = r^2e^{i(2\theta)}$ on the $uv$-plane. If incorrect, how can I show $w$ is on the $uv$-plane in some invariant way (whatever that is)?

about positive real axis:

Let $z \in \mathbb R$. Then $z = x + 0i  \in \mathbb R.$  But $p(z) = x^2 \in \mathbb R$ which gives us $p(\mathbb R) \subseteq \mathbb R$ and $z =x = (\sqrt x)^2 \in p(\mathbb R)$ meaning $\mathbb R \subseteq p(\mathbb R).$

I don't know if this clumsy looking proof makes any sense. If not, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathbb D$ be the unit disk. Asserting that $P(\mathbb D)=\mathbb D$ means two things:

1. $P(\mathbb D)\subset\mathbb D$;
2. $P(\mathbb D)\supset\mathbb D$.

The first one is easy: $\lvert z\rvert<1\implies\lvert z^2\rvert=\lvert z\rvert^2<1$.

You did not even try to prove the second assertion. But it is easy from what you did: if $z\in\mathbb D$, write it as $re^{i\theta}$ ($r\in[0,1)$). But then$$z=\left(\sqrt re^{i\theta/2}\right)^2=P\left(\sqrt re^{i\theta/2}\right).$$

Now, cncerning the set $[0,\infty)$, this simply follows from two facts:

1. every square of an element of $[0,\infty)$ belongs to $[0,\infty)$;
2. if $x\in[0,\infty)$, then $\sqrt x\in[0,\infty)$ and $x=P\left(\sqrt x\right)$.